# docker container fails to start after docker deamon has been restarted

Tags: docker, restart

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with docker 1.11.2. I have configured systemd to automatically restart docker daemon. When I kill the docker daemon, docker daemon restarts, but container will not even it has RestartPolicy set to always. From the logs I can read that it failed to create directory because it exists. I personally think that it related to stopping containerd.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Aug 25 19:20:19 api-31 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Aug 25 19:20:19 api-31 docker[17617]: time="2016-08-25T19:20:19Z" level=info msg="stopping containerd after receiving terminated"
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: docker.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: Closed Docker Socket for the API.
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Aug 25 19:21:49 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:21:49.913162167Z" level=info msg="New containerd process, pid: 19029\n"
Aug 25 19:21:50 api-31 kernel: [87066.742831] audit: type=1400 audit(1472152910.946:23): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=19043 comm="apparmor_parser"
Aug 25 19:21:50 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:21:50.952073973Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"overlay\""
Aug 25 19:21:50 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:21:50.956693893Z" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Aug 25 19:21:50 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:21:50.961641996Z" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Aug 25 19:21:51 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:21:51.016582850Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 66ef9e1af997a1090fac0c89bf96c2631bea32fbe3c238c4349472987957c596 (547bceaad5d121444ddc6effbac3f472d0c232d693d8cc076027e238cf253613)"
Aug 25 19:21:51 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:21:51.046227326Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Aug 25 19:21:51 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:21:51.081106790Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit."
Aug 25 19:21:51 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:21:51.081650610Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Aug 25 19:22:01 api-31 kernel: [87076.922492] docker0: port 1(vethbbc1192) entered disabled state
Aug 25 19:22:01 api-31 kernel: [87076.927128] device vethbbc1192 left promiscuous mode
Aug 25 19:22:01 api-31 kernel: [87076.927131] docker0: port 1(vethbbc1192) entered disabled state
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 docker[19023]: .time="2016-08-25T19:22:03.085800458Z" level=warning msg="error locating sandbox id 66ef9e1af997a1090fac0c89bf96c2631bea32fbe3c238c4349472987957c596: sandbox 66ef9e1af997a1090fac0c89bf96c2631bea32fbe3c238c4349472987957c596 not found"
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:22:03.085907328Z" level=warning msg="failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/547bceaad5d121444ddc6effbac3f472d0c232d693d8cc076027e238cf253613/shm: invalid argument"
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 kernel: [87078.882836] device veth5c6999c entered promiscuous mode
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 kernel: [87078.882984] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth5c6999c: link is not ready
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 systemd-udevd[19128]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth5c6999c: No such file or directory
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 systemd-udevd[19127]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth39fb4d3: No such file or directory
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 kernel: [87078.944218] docker0: port 1(veth5c6999c) entered disabled state
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 kernel: [87078.948636] device veth5c6999c left promiscuous mode
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 kernel: [87078.948640] docker0: port 1(veth5c6999c) entered disabled state
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:22:03.219677059Z" level=error msg="Failed to start container 547bceaad5d121444ddc6effbac3f472d0c232d693d8cc076027e238cf253613: rpc error: code = 6 desc = \"mkdir /run/containerd/547bceaad5d121444ddc6effbac3f472d0c232d693d8cc076027e238cf253613: file exists\""
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:22:03.219750430Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:22:03.219776593Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:22:03.219847738Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=b9f10c9 graphdriver=overlay version=1.11.2
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 25 19:22:03 api-31 docker[19023]: time="2016-08-25T19:22:03.226116336Z" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
```

Answer (score 1):

@VonC - Thank you for pointing me at the right direction. I researched the thread, but in my case the apparmor is not an issue. There are some other issues mentioned in the thread, so I followed them and I found the solution.

SOLUTION:
On Ubuntu 16.04 the problem is that systemd kills process containerd with the docker daemon process. In order to prevent it, you need to add

KillMode=process

to /lib/systemd/system/docker.service and that fixes the issue.

Here are the sources I used:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25246

https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.service#L25

Comment: Well spotted, and more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be followed by [issue 25487](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25487) (August 2016), and was reported even before (April 2016) in [issue 22195](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22195).

Check if you are in the situation mentioned in [issue 21702](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21702#issuecomment-212177160) by [Tõnis Tiigi](https://github.com/tonistiigi):

> This seems to be caused by the apparmor profile for docker daemon we have in [`docker/contrib/apparmor`](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/contrib/apparmor).
>   If this profile is applied in v1.11 (at least ubuntu wily) then container starting does not work.
>
> I'm not sure if users have just manually enforced this profile or apparently we also accidentally installed this profile in 1.10.0-rc1 ([#19707](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19707)).
>
> So the workaround, until we figure out how to deal with this, is to unload the profile with something like `apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/docker-engine` ,delete it and restart daemon.
>   `/etc/apparmor.d/docker` is the profile for the containers and does not need to be changed.